# How can I declare a multi line string in swift 3 which also has html content in it

Tags: swift3

I want to declare a multi line string which also has html content in it and I am passing it as a parameter to compose a mail using MFMailComposeViewDelegate functionality.

How can achieve the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing the swift 3 tag, I assume you can't use the new triple quotes in swift 4.

First method: Concatenation:

You'll have to do it the old-fashioned way:

```
let html = 
    "This is some html\n" +
    "<strong>second line</strong>\n"
```

Second method: write the HTML into a file.

Just create a file called `xxx.html` in your project and write your html in that file. Then, at the start of the app, you can read that file into a string and then you can use it later.

```
let htmlString = try! String(contentsOfFile: Bundle.main.path(forResources: "xxx", ofType: "html"!))
```